# Syncronize data in SQLite / IONIC from neo4j

Tags: sqlite, cordova, neo4j, synchronization, ionic-framework

I have an ionic application that uses SQLite to store data. The data is retrieved from an HTTP REST Service, which then connects to a neo4j database. I need to be able to sync the changing data or insert any new data into my sqlite database as the data changes on the neo4j server. What is the best way to do this? Are there any existing frameworks? I am aware of PouchDB, but that doesn't really fit with what I am doing. I can't use local storage or any other in-memory storage as there could be a lot of data.

Answer (score 0):

You may find these [neo4j data integration](http://neo4j.com/docs/stable/capabilities-data-integration.html) articles helpful:

1. [Import Data Into Neo4j](http://neo4j.com/developer/guide-importing-data-and-etl/)
2. [Data Migration between MySQL and Neo4j](http://neo4j.com/blog/data-migration-between-mysql-and-neo4j/)